# Facebook Graph API, message field returns null when reading news feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My intention is to get the most recent post from the users feed, however the line below does not bring expected results when a wall post is posted on the timeline by a friend, but works well when its posted by the user himself

```
me/feed?fields=from,id,message&limit=1
```

All the fields in the above line return values except for the message field. It works fine in my other Facebook account, but it does not work in the other one.

```
{
"data": [
{
  "from": {
    "name": "Ted Mad",
    "id": "100000145467923"
  },
  "id": "1841029522785868_1841280962760724"
}
],
"paging": {
"previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/1841029522785868/feed?fields=from,id,message&limit=1&format=json&since=1483606096&access_token=EAACEdEose0cBALrWazFWFoRt9VNGZCknu1MDAkUU1jFZBtdPv8rl3F7frMYHtw7Jeslr8uN8XT7un2lXx3U7AtdZCDu8rBz0ZBppxEXYZC3gv61D3Sa8N86SugoPmY0Rg4aJaZCyJQswQVRxiXUBcZAawTHXMsyvp8uGpc0J1HVcExzQ4509OUxzgbWJ2vVyMMZD&__paging_token=enc_AdAqFkXrZAVv9E0mFWSLfmXZCbmAaYl9qCH33z4aZCOxo2xlVYtIcKGIfLDAivHJANP4DkU06kDEPr6TCN8g4kawFjRt3gaxEZApj0sJb7ioEkO3lAZDZD&__previous=1",
"next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/1841029522785868/feed fields=from,id,message&limit=1&format=json&access_token=EAACEdEose0cBALrWazFWFoRt9VNGZCknu1MDAkUU1jFZBtdPv8rl3F7frMYHtw7Jeslr8uN8XT7un2lXx3U7AtdZCDu8rBz0ZBppxEXYZC3gv61D3Sa8N86SugoPmY0Rg4aJaZCyJQswQVRxiXUBcZAawTHXMsyvp8uGpc0J1HVcExzQ4509OUxzgbWJ2vVyMMZD&until=1483606096&__paging_token=enc_AdAqFkXrZAVv9E0mFWSLfmXZCbmAaYl9qCH33z4aZCOxo2xlVYtIcKGIfLDAivHJANP4DkU06kDEPr6TCN8g4kawFjRt3gaxEZApj0sJb7ioEkO3lAZDZD"
}
}
```

Comment: can you add the json values for the wrong wall posts?

Comment: Are you sure there's a value for 'message'? It might actually be null, but have a value in 'story' or have attachments

Comment: The wall post i am reading, is only text, no links, no attachments and no photos. When i read the same post (same text word for word) using a different account, the value of the message field is displayed. @Igy

Comment: Most likely your app does not have permission to view the post with the access token used. FYI., you are only allowed to have one personal FB account.